# How to make desgin using html css for a container or box having c shaped cut in between of left and right edge

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please help me to do this design using react native

i am expecting the design that i attached image
[image]

the card is like rectangular shaped ishould have c shaped cut in between the left and right side of edge of container in react native

Comment: `svg`, `clip-path` and/or `pseudo-elements`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: ? svg, clip-path and pseudo-elements are vanilla CSS and HTML features...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have created. It is very flexible and you can change almost anything from the variables in the `CSS`. The `CSS` is lengthy as there is nothing like `inner border-radius` so I had to create it myself. Export that as a component and use it anywhere.

The chopt places in the middle are actual hols so everything from below will be visible.

If you want to put content inside, you could do that inside the `cardBody` elements

```css
:root {
  --cardWidth: 200px;
  --cardHeight: 120px;
}

.card {
  --backgroundColor: #ffffff;
  --borderColor: #dddddd;
  --borderSize: 1px;
  --middleChipSize: 10px;
  --borderRadius: 10px;

  position: relative;
  width: var(--cardWidth);
  height: var(--cardHeight);
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.card .cardBody {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - var(--borderSize) * 2);
  height: calc(50% - var(--middleChipSize) - var(--borderSize));
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
  border: solid var(--borderSize) var(--borderColor);
}

.card .cardBody:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius) var(--borderRadius) 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.card .cardBody:nth-child(5) {
  border-radius: 0px 0px var(--borderRadius) var(--borderRadius);
  border-top: none;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - var(--middleChipSize) * 2);
  height: var(--middleChipSize);
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle .cardBodyMiddleEdge {
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--middleChipSize);
  height: var(--middleChipSize);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle .cardBodyMiddleEdge::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border: calc(var(--middleChipSize) / 2) solid var(--backgroundColor);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle .cardBodyMiddleEdge::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(200% + var(--borderSize));
  height: calc(200% + var(--borderSize));
  border: calc(var(--middleChipSize) / 2) solid var(--borderColor);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(2) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(1) {
  left: calc(var(--middleChipSize) * -1);
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(2) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(1)::after {
  top: -50%;
  right: -50%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(2) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(1)::before {
  top: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
  right: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(2) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(2) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(2)::after {
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(2) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(2)::before {
  top: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
  left: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(4) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(1) {
  left: calc(var(--middleChipSize) * -1);
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(4) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(1)::after {
  bottom: -50%;
  right: -50%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(4) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(1)::before {
  bottom: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
  right: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(4) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(4) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(2)::after {
  bottom: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}

.card .cardBodyMiddle:nth-child(4) .cardBodyMiddleEdge:nth-child(2)::before {
  bottom: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
  left: calc(-50% + var(--borderSize));
}

.card .cardMiddleLine {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - var(--middleChipSize) * 2 - 30px);
  height: var(--borderSize);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: var(--borderColor);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardBody"></div>
  <div class="cardBodyMiddle">
    <div class="cardBodyMiddleEdge"></div>
    <div class="cardBodyMiddleEdge"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardMiddleLine"></div>
  <div class="cardBodyMiddle">
    <div class="cardBodyMiddleEdge"></div>
    <div class="cardBodyMiddleEdge"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardBody"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works it is a nasty solution to a simple task. Instead of using 10 elements and over 100 lines of CSS code you could simply use the `clip-path` route which adds one property in css.

Comment: this is working fine in reactjs, can we do in react native mobile

Comment: @tacoshy you cannot make `clip-path` with that shape as it should includes `polygon` and `circle` at the same time and thins is not possible. If you still think this is possible, please provide an answer with the `clip-path` solution